# Problema login jsp & servlet con atributo boolean administrador en clase usuario

Tags: java, jsp, aplicación-web, servlets

Tengo problemas para registrarme, antes solo me registraba como usuario y funcionaba, ahora me registro como administrador y no entra, y si me registro como usuario entra en la ruta /admin, dejo código como muestra para que se vea el error. Tengo una clase pojo que es Usuario en la que un atributo es boolean administrador.

El filtro para los usuarios: (Decir que solo quiero un administrador para todo cuyas credenciales son siempre admin,admin)

```
@WebFilter("/app/*")
public class FiltroRegistro implements Filter {


    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        String loginURI = req.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp";


        if (session != null && session.getAttribute("usuario") != null) {

            chain.doFilter(req, res);

        } else {
            res.sendRedirect(loginURI);
        }

    }
```

El filtro para el administrador:

```
@WebFilter("/admin/*") public class FiltroAdministrador implements
   Filter {
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        String loginURI = req.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp";

        if (session != null && session.getAttribute("administrador") != null) {

                chain.doFilter(req, res);

        } else {
            res.sendRedirect(loginURI);
        }

    }
```

El servlet de registro:

```
@WebServlet("/FiltroServlet")
public class FiltroRegistroServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String nombreUsuario = request.getParameter("nombreUsuario");
        String contrasenia = request.getParameter("contrasenia");

        GestionUsuarios gestionUsuarios = new GestionUsuarios();

        Usuario admin = gestionUsuarios.registrarAdministrador(nombreUsuario, contrasenia);
        //Usuario admin = gestionUsuarios.registrarAdministrador(nombreUsuario, contrasenia);
        Usuario usuario = gestionUsuarios.registrarUsuario(nombreUsuario, contrasenia);

        if (admin != null) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("administrador", admin);

            response.sendRedirect("admin/TablaEventosAdmin");


        } else if (usuario != null) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
            response.sendRedirect("app/TablaEventosServlet");
            response.sendRedirect("loginError.jsp");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        }

    }
```

Método registro de usuario en Capa de negocio:

```
public Usuario registrarUsuario(String nombreUsuario, String contrasenia) {
        return daoUsuario.ObtenerUsuarioPorNombreYContrasenia(new Usuario(nombreUsuario, contrasenia, false));

    }
```

Método registro de administrador en capa de negocio:

```
public Usuario registrarAdministrador(String usuario, String contrasenia){

        return daoUsuario.ObtenerUsuarioPorNombreYContrasenia(new Usuario(usuario,contrasenia, true));
    }
```

En la misma capa de negocio donde tengo los métodos de registro tengo creado el administrador así:

```
public GestionUsuarios() {
        daoUsuario = new DaoUsuarioHibernate();
        //Creamos el administrador
        Usuario admin = new Usuario("admin", "admin", true);
        //Añadimos el administrador
        daoUsuario.add(admin);
    }
```

Muestro la estructura de carpetas para que sea más fácil ver la idea de lo que quiero conseguir:

[image: El administrador entraría en admin y los demas usuarios en app]

Answer (score 1):

Lo normal es que tuvieras una tabla en base de datos para los usuarios como pareces tener, pero creo que te falta un campo adicional en esa tabla donde indiques el rol o perfil que tiene ese usuario.

Tu método `registrarUsuario` seria suficiente, sobraría `registrarAdministrador`, pero no deberías pasar ese boolean, sino que es la base de datos la que te dirá si el usuario tiene el perfil administrador o no. (Edita tu pregunta y añade el código de Usuario)

Quedaría algo así:

```
public Usuario registrarUsuario(String nombreUsuario, String contrasenia) {
    return daoUsuario.ObtenerUsuarioPorNombreYContrasenia(new Usuario(nombreUsuario, contrasenia));    
}
```

Tu servlet quedaría algo así:

```
@WebServlet("/FiltroServlet")
public class FiltroRegistroServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String nombreUsuario = request.getParameter("nombreUsuario");
        String contrasenia = request.getParameter("contrasenia");

        GestionUsuarios gestionUsuarios = new GestionUsuarios();

        Usuario usuario = gestionUsuarios.registrarUsuario(nombreUsuario, contrasenia);

        if (usuario != null && Rol.ADMIN.equals(usuario.getRol()) ) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("administrador", admin);

            response.sendRedirect("admin/TablaEventosAdmin");


        } else if (usuario != null && Rol.USER.equals(usuario.getRol()) ) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
            response.sendRedirect("app/TablaEventosServlet");
            response.sendRedirect("loginError.jsp");

        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        }

    }
```

Actualmente, tal cual esta planteado, si efectivamente tienes una sola tabla para los usuarios, si el nombre y contraseña son correctos siempre te dirá que son administradores por que es lo primero que compruebas, pero si alternaras el if, te diría lo contrario, que son siempre usuarios.